# create nested loop of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create a small nested loop that will create divs from my `h1` and `h2`/`h3` tags. I realize this may be redundant with other questions so at the least I'd like to be pointed in the right direction :)

Given this HTML:

```
<h1>LEVEL 1.1</h1>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.1</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.2</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.3</h2>
<h1>LEVEL 1.2</h1>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.4</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.5</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.6</h2>
<h1>LEVEL 1.3</h1>
<h2>SECTION 2.7</h2>
<h2>SECTION 2.8</h2>
<h2>SECTION 2.9</h2>
```

I'd like to create new HTML (in the desired output)

```js
  const h1_div = function(nm) {
    return `<div class="level-1-header">${nm}</div>`
  }
  
  const h2_div = function(num, nm) {
    return `<div class="topic" index=${num}>${nm}</div>`
  }
    
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var headings = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3");
    
    H1_divs = [];
    H2_divs = [];
    
    all_divs = [];
    
    // create a loop that makes an H1 div
    // and puts all the H2 divs inside it
    
    /*
    <div "level-1-header">LEVEL 1.1
     <div class="topic" index="1">SECTION 2.1</div>
     <div class="topic" index="2">SECTION 2.2</div>
     <div class="topic" index="3">SECTION 2.3</div>
    </div>
    
    <div "level-1-header">LEVEL 1.2
     <div class="topic" index="4">SECTION 2.4</div>
     <div class="topic" index="5">SECTION 2.5</div>
     <div class="topic" index="6">SECTION 2.6</div>
    </div>
    
    <div "level-1-header">LEVEL 1.3
     <div class="topic" index="7">SECTION 2.7</div>
     <div class="topic" index="8">SECTION 2.8</div>
     <div class="topic" index="9">SECTION 2.9</div>
    </div>
    */
    
    test = [];
    // loop over the h1 
    // and within every h1 make the h2s
    for (i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
      if (headings[i].tagName === "H1") {
        H1_divs += h1_div(headings[i].innerText)
        for (j = 0; j < headings.length; j++) {
          if (headings[j].tagName !== "H1") {
            // this is definitely wrong
            H2_divs += h2_div(j, headings[j].innerText)
          }
        }
        test = test + H2_divs
      }
    }
    
    // not quite right
   console.log(test)
   // put that created element inside #section-toc
   document.getElementById("section-toc").innerHTML = all_divs
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section-toc"></div>

<h1>LEVEL 1.1</h1>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.1</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.2</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.3</h2>
<h1>LEVEL 1.2</h1>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.4</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.5</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.6</h2>
<h1>LEVEL 1.3</h1>
<h2>SECTION 2.7</h2>
<h2>SECTION 2.8</h2>
<h2>SECTION 2.9</h2>
```

## Desired Result:

```
<div "level-1-header">LEVEL 1.1
     <div class="topic" index="1">SECTION 2.1</div>
     <div class="topic" index="2">SECTION 2.2</div>
     <div class="topic" index="3">SECTION 2.3</div>
    </div>
    
    <div "level-1-header">LEVEL 1.2
     <div class="topic" index="4">SECTION 2.4</div>
     <div class="topic" index="5">SECTION 2.5</div>
     <div class="topic" index="6">SECTION 2.6</div>
    </div>
    
    <div "level-1-header">LEVEL 1.3
     <div class="topic" index="7">SECTION 2.7</div>
     <div class="topic" index="8">SECTION 2.8</div>
     <div class="topic" index="9">SECTION 2.9</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I made a pen too if that's easier to work with: https://codepen.io/MayaRGans/pen/qBaabxX?editors=1012

Comment: What is your question?  Post generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```js
const h1_div = function(nm) {
  return `<div class='level-1-header'>${nm}</div>`
}

const h2_div = function(nm, num) {
  return `<div class="topic" index=${num}>${nm}</div>`
}

const replaceHtml = function(tag, htmlFunction) {
  var $tag = $(tag);
  for (var i = 0; i < $tag.length; i++) {
    var currentTag = $tag[i];
    var $newHtml = $(htmlFunction(currentTag.innerHTML, i+1));
    $(currentTag).replaceWith($newHtml);
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
 replaceHtml("h1", h1_div);
 replaceHtml("h2", h2_div);
 console.log(document.getElementById("section-toc").innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section-toc">
<h1>LEVEL 1.1</h1>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.1</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.2</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.3</h2>
<h1>LEVEL 1.2</h1>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.4</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.5</h2>
<h2 class="section">SECTION 2.6</h2>
<h1>LEVEL 1.3</h1>
<h2>SECTION 2.7</h2>
<h2>SECTION 2.8</h2>
<h2>SECTION 2.9</h2>
</div>
```